# ScrollViewer of WPF - How focus content

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I have Providing TabControl, on TabControl I have many TabItem, and during each TabItem I have many ScrollViewer, and on each ScrollViewer I have StackPanel

1) When I try to scroll down/up, With mouse -> Scroll works fine

2) When I try to Click on content of StackPanel  and touch up/down of keyboard -> Scroll  works fine

But I case of changing tabitem of TabControl, I can't use Keyboard(Up/Down),and it's not works.

Am I must to provide .KeyDown+= , and attention which tabItem is active, or I could focus content of tabItem during touching tabItem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, your view looks something like

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="First tab">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="2000"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Second tab">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="2000"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

and you want to set your keyboard focus to the content of the `TabItem` whenever the selected tab is changed. If so, one possible solution would be to make the contents focusable and explicitly set the keyboard focus whenever the selected tab changes; that is, do something like

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControlSelectionChanged">
    <TabItem Header="First tab">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="2000" Focusable="True"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Second tab">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="2000" Focusable="True"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

where `TabControlSelectionChanged` is given by

```
private void TabControlSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
    ((e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem)?.Content as ScrollViewer)?.Focus();
```